# Possible performance issue in pine script

Tags: pine-script

I have a indicator to add bar number on each 5 mins bar for every two bars, see below. It is working well but it seems making the web page quite "lagging", any idea what could be the problem? I know it is a performance issue but being new to pinescript I am not sure where could be the cause...Also is there a better way to do what I want to achieve? see picture below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpstA.png)

My current code below:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w73Tz.png)

```
study("Count Bars Day",overlay=true)

is_new_day() => 
    d=dayofweek
    na(d[1]) or d != d[1]
    
plotchar((barssince(is_new_day())+1)==2,char='',transp=75,text="2",textcolor=black,location=location.belowbar)
plotchar((barssince(is_new_day())+1)==4,char='',transp=75,text="4",textcolor=black,location=location.belowbar)
plotchar((barssince(is_new_day())+1)==6,char='',transp=75,text="6",textcolor=black,location=location.belowbar)
plotchar((barssince(is_new_day())+1)==8,char='',transp=75,text="8",textcolor=black,location=location.belowbar)
plotchar((barssince(is_new_day())+1)==10,char='',transp=75,text="10",textcolor=black,location=location.belowbar)
plotchar((barssince(is_new_day())+1)==12,char='',transp=50,text="12",textcolor=blue,location=location.belowbar)
plotchar((barssince(is_new_day())+1)==14,char='',transp=75,text="14",textcolor=black,location=location.belowbar)
plotchar((barssince(is_new_day())+1)==16,char='',transp=75,text="16",textcolor=black,location=location.belowbar)
plotchar((barssince(is_new_day())+1)==18,char='',transp=50,text="18",textcolor=red,location=location.belowbar)

plotchar((barssince(is_new_day())+1)==20,char='',transp=75,text="20",textcolor=black,location=location.belowbar)
plotchar((barssince(is_new_day())+1)==22,char='',transp=75,text="22",textcolor=black,location=location.belowbar)
plotchar((barssince(is_new_day())+1)==24,char='',transp=75,text="24",textcolor=black,location=location.belowbar)
plotchar((barssince(is_new_day())+1)==26,char='',transp=75,text="26",textcolor=black,location=location.belowbar)
plotchar((barssince(is_new_day())+1)==28,char='',transp=75,text="28",textcolor=black,location=location.belowbar)
plotchar((barssince(is_new_day())+1)==30,char='',transp=50,text="30",textcolor=blue,location=location.belowbar)
plotchar((barssince(is_new_day())+1)==32,char='',transp=75,text="32",textcolor=black,location=location.belowbar)
plotchar((barssince(is_new_day())+1)==34,char='',transp=75,text="34",textcolor=black,location=location.belowbar)
plotchar((barssince(is_new_day())+1)==36,char='',transp=75,text="36",textcolor=black,location=location.belowbar)

plotchar((barssince(is_new_day())+1)==38,char='',transp=75,text="38",textcolor=black,location=location.belowbar)
plotchar((barssince(is_new_day())+1)==40,char='',transp=75,text="40",textcolor=black,location=location.belowbar)
plotchar((barssince(is_new_day())+1)==42,char='',transp=75,text="42",textcolor=black,location=location.belowbar)
plotchar((barssince(is_new_day())+1)==44,char='',transp=75,text="44",textcolor=black,location=location.belowbar)
plotchar((barssince(is_new_day())+1)==46,char='',transp=75,text="46",textcolor=black,location=location.belowbar)
plotchar((barssince(is_new_day())+1)==48,char='',transp=50,text="48",textcolor=blue,location=location.belowbar)
plotchar((barssince(is_new_day())+1)==50,char='',transp=75,text="50",textcolor=black,location=location.belowbar)
plotchar((barssince(is_new_day())+1)==52,char='',transp=75,text="52",textcolor=black,location=location.belowbar)
plotchar((barssince(is_new_day())+1)==54,char='',transp=75,text="54",textcolor=black,location=location.belowbar)

plotchar((barssince(is_new_day())+1)==56,char='',transp=75,text="56",textcolor=black,location=location.belowbar)
plotchar((barssince(is_new_day())+1)==58,char='',transp=75,text="58",textcolor=black,location=location.belowbar)
plotchar((barssince(is_new_day())+1)==60,char='',transp=75,text="60",textcolor=black,location=location.belowbar)
plotchar((barssince(is_new_day())+1)==62,char='',transp=75,text="62",textcolor=black,location=location.belowbar)
plotchar((barssince(is_new_day())+1)==64,char='',transp=75,text="64",textcolor=black,location=location.belowbar)
plotchar((barssince(is_new_day())+1)==66,char='',transp=50,text="66",textcolor=blue,location=location.belowbar)
plotchar((barssince(is_new_day())+1)==68,char='',transp=75,text="68",textcolor=black,location=location.belowbar)
plotchar((barssince(is_new_day())+1)==70,char='',transp=75,text="70",textcolor=black,location=location.belowbar)
plotchar((barssince(is_new_day())+1)==72,char='',transp=75,text="72",textcolor=black,location=location.belowbar)

plotchar((barssince(is_new_day())+1)==74,char='',transp=75,text="74",textcolor=black,location=location.belowbar)
plotchar((barssince(is_new_day())+1)==76,char='',transp=75,text="76",textcolor=black,location=location.belowbar)
plotchar((barssince(is_new_day())+1)==78,char='',transp=75,text="78",textcolor=black,location=location.belowbar)
```

Comment: Have you considered using `labels`? It would be much easier. But there is a limit on the number of labels you can have on script.

Comment: not yet, I am totally new to pine script. there are 78 five minutes bars on SPY each day, not sure if 78 is beyond the limit?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue doesn't appear in Chrome, I was using Firefox. Guess I will just switch to Chrome. But thank you!